# How do I skip validating the URI in lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using lxml to parse some xml files. I don't create them, I'm just parsing them. Some of the files contain invalid uri's for the namespaces. For instance:

```
'D:\Path\To\some\local\file.xsl'
```

I get an error when I try to process it:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlns:xsi: 'D:\Path\To\some\local\file.xsl' is not a valid URI
```

Is there an easy way to replace any invalid uri's with something (anything, such as  'http://www.googlefsdfsd.com/')? I thought of writing a regex but was hoping for an easier way.

Comment: What is googlefsdfsd.com/ ? It looks pretty broken to me

Comment: It doesn't matter. It doesn't have to be a VALID url, just a url (something that isn't a local filename).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the parser doesn't like are the backslashes in the namespace uri.

To parse the xml despite the invalid uris, you can instantiate an [lxml.etree.XMLParser](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html) with the `recover` argument set to `True` and then use that to parse the file:

```py
from lxml import etree
recovering_parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
xml = etree.parse("xmlfile.xml", parser=recovering_parser)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that those specific errors are not significant to your use case you could just catch it as an exeption:

```
try:
   # process your tree here
   SomeFn()

except lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError, e:
   print "Ignoring", e
   pass
```

Comment: The error doesn't happen while _processing_ the tree. A namespace uri containing backslashes results in an error while _parsing_ the document, so you don't even get to the point where you have a tree, catching the error won't help.

Comment: Then it may be you you need to use one of `r'D:\Path\To\some\local\file.xsl'` or `'D:\\Path\\To\\some\\local\\file.xsl'` or `'D:/Path/To/some/local/file.xsl'` or possibly `'file:D:\Path\To\some\local\file.xsl'`

Comment: The uris aren't within the python code, they're within the xml files, so prefixing them with `r` or double escaping the backslashes doesn't make any sense (and i don't think changing all files to replace backslashes would be an option - the OP just wants to parse the documents).

Comment: There is always the easy option of just reporting that the XML is invalid - which it is due to invalid URI so that should really be resolved rather than worked around.